# Default .Net 6 MVC Web App Template: The view 'Index' was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I created a brand new web app in VS2022 using the "ASP.Net Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)" Template in .Net 6

I ran the application and got this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found.
```

I haven't changed any of the template code.

Very strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found one way to get it working...although its not clear to me why this works:

Add this package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation**

and then change `services.AddControllersWithViews()` in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact problem. We just updated Visual Studio 17.8.x to the latest 17.9.2 and then it worked. Just reopen the old project and run it, you dont even need to recreate the project with the new template.